# Kinect + SpCreateDefaultObjectFromCategoryId = SPERR_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c++, kinect, speech-recognition, sapi

I've created a solution which uses the microsoft SAPI to recognize speech defined in a grammar file.

On its own, this code works fine. However, when I integrate it with the same program which is running the Kinect SDK, it fails on the line:

```
hr = cpRecognizer->SpGetDefaultTokenFromCategoryId(SPCAT_AUDIOIN,&pAudioToken);
//At this point, HR == -2147200966 == SPERR_NOT_FOUND
```

I have tried plugging in a microphone which is external to the kinect into an available microphone port and setting it to be the default microphone. This did not bring me any joy, either.

I then use the pAudioToken to call cpRecognizer->SetInput(pAudioToken,TRUE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you need to take into account is the difference between the desktop SAPI recognizers and the server SAPI recognizers.  Unfortunately, it's very tricky to determine (from visual inspection) which one you're including - they're both named sapi.h, but the category IDs are different.

One easy difference is that SAPI_VER is 0x055 for the server version, but 0x054 or less for desktop.

However, the key difference here is that SPCAT_AUDIOIN (the audio input category) is named differently in the server SAPI header and the desktop SAPI header, and it's entirely possible that there is no default token for the audio input category **for the server recognizer**.

Plugging a microphone in would not change the **server recognizer's** idea of what the default input would be, although it would change the desktop recognizer's default input.

I would recommend iterating through the audio input category using the [SpEnumTokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee450729%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) helper to see which input devices are available.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you. I will give this a go to see what the deal is - currently though, I can't find the SAPI_VER constant...

Comment: When I call the following:

hr = SpEnumTokens(SPCAT_AUDIOIN,NULL,NULL, &cpEnum);
//hr == S_OK
hr = cpEnum->GetCount(&ulNumTokens);
//ulNumTokens == 0

Comment: OK, let's step back a bit.  What you *really* want is to do speech recognition from the Kinect audio input, right?  If that's the case, then rather than using ISpObjectToken, you should use the stream interfaces (ISpStream, ISpStreamFormat, ISpAudio).  Since I'm unfamiliar with the Kinect SDK, what are the audio interfaces available to you?

Comment: The first answer to this question:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdkaudioapi/thread/7456b96d-f4d7-4d59-bace-2b8e492c6aae

Gives all the detail necessary to answer that question - however, no-one on the forums have been able to figure out how to implement what he is saying. I was hoping that I would be able to just use an external microphone, but that doesn't work with this method.

Comment: Here's a bit of a disconnect.  I can probably tell you what the WAVFORMATEX should be, if you can tell me how to get the audio stream. :)  Again, I don't know *anything* about the kinect, but I do know a lot about SAPI.

Comment: Actually, that the thread above doesn't help much, but this one does: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdkaudioapi/thread/4f9f3a50-5347-483c-8b1b-11875f85dc86 - in particular, the comment about the audiocaptureraw sample should help you get the raw audio stream, and then the IAudioClient::GetMixFormat should get you an appropriate WAVEFORMATEX.

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet, but I guess this is enough information to get started... Currently, I'm still a bit fuzzy with how exactly this will be done, but I guess all I can do is try.